# How to handle CancelledError with python 3.8 unittest IsolatedAsyncioTestCase

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I would like to ask question on handling asyncio.CancelledError from **IsolatedAsyncioTestCase**, which is provided for testing asyncio on py3.8

Given following testcases

```py
import unittest
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase
import asyncio


class Test(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('setup')

    async def asyncSetUp(self):
        print('async setup')

    async def test_response(self):
        print('test_response')
        self.addAsyncCleanup(self.on_cleanup)

    def tearDown(self):
        print('teardown')

    async def asyncTearDown(self):
        print('before async teardown')
        fut = asyncio.Future()
        fut.cancel()
        await fut
        print('after async teardown')

    async def on_cleanup(self):
        print('clean up')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It got sucked on tearDown

```
root@1318a3fe59d0:/# python --version
Python 3.8.0
root@1318a3fe59d0:/# python /workspace/b.py 
setup
async setup
test_response
before async teardown
....
```

After digging into the error stack (by pressing CTRL+C to terminate the process), and source codes from [github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7264e92b718d307cc499b2f10eab7644b00f0499/Lib/unittest/async_case.py), these are codes related to this error.

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7264e92b718d307cc499b2f10eab7644b00f0499/Lib/unittest/async_case.py#L126
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7264e92b718d307cc499b2f10eab7644b00f0499/Lib/unittest/async_case.py#L105

Error **asyncio.CancelledError** has been selectively raised but not other exception. So, I am wondering how to catch and handle this error instead of hanging into the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I found a [similar issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue39101) from python's ticket system.

Hopefully, it was resolved on 2020-12-16. Moreover, by [checking what they modified](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/d549d0b5575b390431b7b26999151f79f74d4516) in 3.8 branch, they change how they catch exceptions.

So, as long as you have latest python, which include this fix, you should not have this issue again.